# SharePoint Timer job with no name

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs

My client has an On-Prem SharePoint 2013 Farm consisting of 2 WFE, 2 App Servers, and Index Server and a DB Server.

One of the WFE's has a Timer Job that fails at around 06:21 every morning. The problem is the Timer Job name is blank

[image]

I've looked through the log for 'Failed','Time Out' and 'expired' but can't find anything that relates to a Timer Job. I'm at a loss where to investigate next.

Does anyone have any idea how I can find out what this job is trying to do but unable to because it times out ? Or any ideas how to get rid of it altogether ?

All ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: If you try getting the timer jobs object in PowerShell, perhaps you get some more information.

Comment: You could try something like Get-SPTimerJob | ?{ $_.Title -like ""} | FL

Comment: Thanks Ben - unfortunately the PowerShell you suggested didn't return any results. Dan

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the syntax as I had no SP farm at hand. I can verify it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Job History, and find the failed timer job. Check if you could click it on Job Title value. If yes, click it. Then you will open the timer job's settings page, check the Job Description to find if there is something about it.

Do you have customization on your farm? you can check if it is a customize timer job that your developers develop.

And also in the timer job settings page, you can disable the timer job via clicking "Disable" button.

Comment: Kally, thanks for your suggestion. I will double check if there is anything in the Job Description but I don't think there was. To answer your second question, Yes - there is customisation on the site. My gut instinct is this is being generated by 3rd party software, but it would be nice to be able to prove it......I'll update further when I've checked the Job Description. Thanks again.......Dan

Comment: Checked the Job History and the blank space where the Job Title should be is not clickable. If I click in the word 'Failed' I end up back where I started with the screenshot I put in the original post. Any luck with that Powershell Ben ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I finally managed to get something from the ULS Logs

The job belonged to Nintex and was a recycle job for the Nintex Live Workflow Queue Service

In the ULS log the job was called nwl-queue-recycle-execute-(guid) . I only managed to trace it by the Start and End times of the job matched exactly the times in the Timer Job History.

Dan